# How to handle after insert postgresql trigger with referencing the inserted column?

Tags: postgresql-15

I created an After Insert trigger named "ABC" to send data required by the process "A". However, the process "A" will keep checking to see new record (inserted record of above trigger) exists before it executes.
As the result, no record exist - the insert event hasn't complete which caused by the process "A" that's still executing. So the process "A" keeps checking which lead to the inserted row will not complete. It looks like it becomes infinite loop.

How should I handle this scenario?
Thanks, appreciated your advices.

Comment: Abstract questions are unlikely to garner useful responses. Please edit the post to include the actual code, associated DDL, sample input, and expected output as formatted text.